# I get success as the JSON response when I use DELETE method even though the id does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I want to delete an item by their id but I get a successful response even though the ID does not exist.

```
exports.deleteItemById = (req, res, next) => {

       Item.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (error, item) => {
        if(error){
           return res.status(201).json({
                success: false,
                message: "Item could not be found"
            })
        }
        res.status(200).json({
          success: true
        });
      }); 
    };
```

For example, 
if I use the following item ID: 5d540f7c69a372ddc13dc77f to delete one of the items using Postman, it works and deletes the item and shows "success: true" as the JSON response  but in the next try, if I use the same ID, I still get "success: true" which is not the result I want. I want to get "Item could not be found" message if the ID does not exist anymore.

Comment: Can you share your findByIdAndDelete method as well?

Comment: What frameworks are you using?

Comment: @adrenalin  I am using Express framework.

Comment: @LordOfSun I did not write findByIdAndDelete. It is a function provided by Mongoose. Here is the link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete

Comment: Please don't use 2xx status codes for failures. Your code returns http status code 201 (created) in case delete failed. If you want to convey an error, you should use either a 4xx or a 5xx status code, depending on the actual error. That way it becomes very easy to use the api, because you do not _have to_ read the response body.

Comment: @Arjan Got it, bro. Thanks!

Comment: @jaxonflexonwaxon Express doesn't have any databases out of the box, you should include the database adapters as well when asking in the future so that we can provide you the correct information. :)

Comment: @adrenalin Well, I am banned from asking any more questions. I will keep this in mind when I can start asking questions again after six months lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this will not give an error because in mongoDB if the document is not found it simply returns as `{ "nRemoved" : 0 }`. If you want to check if the item was existing you have to check for the deleted document. Please refer to the below code.

```
exports.deleteItemById = (req, res, next) => {

   Item.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (error, item) => {
    if(!item){ // this will be null if no document with the mentioned id existed
       return res.status(201).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Item could not be found"
        })
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true
    });
  }); 
};
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete) say:

1. `findByIdAndDelete` is an alias for `findOneAndDelete`
2. `findOneAndDelete` "Finds a matching document, removes it, and passes the found document (if any) to the callback."

So, just check if a document (`item`) is returned:

```
exports.deleteItemById = (req, res, next) => {

       Item.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, (error, item) => {
        if(!item){
           return res.status(201).json({
                success: false,
                message: "Item could not be found"
            })
        }
        res.status(200).json({
          success: true
        });
      }); 
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was what I was looking for.